# Prove that there are only finite $\lambda^T A\in \mathbb{Z}^{m}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, integers

How can I prove that there are only finite $\lambda^T A\in \mathbb{Z}^{m}$ where $A \in \mathbb{Z}^{m\times n}$ ( fixed) and $\lambda \in [0,1]^m$. My intuition says it is true but I have no idea to prove it.

(Also not sure about the right tags)

Comment: What is $t$? What do you mean by "there are only finite $\lambda^tA$"? This question is very unclear.

Comment: Transposed, but I remember now that should be capital

Comment: But what does it mean "There are only finite $\lambda^TA$"? And what the heck is $\lambda ^T$ if $\lambda$ is a real number? What exactly is $\frac12^T$, for example?

Comment: Maybe this edit makes the question more clear

Comment: Ow forgot a very important part still, editing

Comment: I still have no idea what you mean by "there are only finite".

Comment: Now it should be alright

Comment: $\lambda^TA$ is a single vector. I don't know what you mean by saying that there is only a finite of it.

Comment: Well as lambda can be any combination of any number between 0 and 1 as a vector and A is fixed, I have to prove that there are only finite vectors with only integer numbers

Comment: Yeah, the set might have been a good addition to the question

Answer (score 1):

Show that:

1. For a given $A\in\mathbb{Z}^{m\times n}$, the set $S_A=\{\lambda^T A, \lambda\in[0,1]^m\}$ is bounded.
2. A bounded subset of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ is finite.